# Using validation groups on EasyAdmin 3.x

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, easyadmin

I want to use validation groups with EasyAdmin 3.x when creating a new User to validate every field.

I have a User entity with *name*, *phone*, and *email* fields and use @UniqueEntity in a "creation" group, so I can update the User in a form I created outside from EasyAdmin. That works just fine, but I can't manage to find how to tell EasyAdmin to use the Default group *and* my creation group when I am using the *new* action.

Here is the simplified User entity with the constraints I have

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=LeadRepository::class)
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *  fields="cellphone",
 *  message="Ya existe un usuario con este número telefónico",
 *  groups={"creation"}
 * )
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *  fields="email",
 *  message="Ya existe un usuario con este email",
 *  groups={"creation"}
 * )
 */
class Lead
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="bigint", unique=true, options={"unsigned"=true})
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Length(
     *  min = 10,
     *  max = 10
     * )
     */
    private $phone;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\Email
     */
    private $email;
```

And the full LeadCrudController used with EasyAdmin

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use App\Entity\Lead;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\Action;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\Actions;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\Crud;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AbstractCrudController;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\AssociationField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\DateTimeField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\EmailField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\IntegerField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\TelephoneField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\TextField;

class LeadCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
    public static function getEntityFqcn(): string
    {
        return Lead::class;
    }

    public function configureCrud(Crud $crud): Crud
    {
        return $crud
            ->setEntityLabelInSingular('Lead')
            ->setEntityLabelInPlural('Lead')
            ->setSearchFields(['id', 'name', 'cellphone', 'email'])
            ->setDefaultSort(['createdAt' => 'DESC'])
        ;
    }

    public function configureActions(Actions $actions): Actions
    {
        return $actions
            ->disable('delete')
            ->add(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, Action::DETAIL)
            ->setPermission(Action::DETAIL, 'ROLE_ADMIN')
            ->setPermission(Action::INDEX, 'ROLE_ADMIN')
            ->setPermission(Action::EDIT, 'ROLE_ADMIN')
            ->setPermission(Action::SAVE_AND_RETURN, 'ROLE_ADMIN')
            ->setPermission(Action::SAVE_AND_CONTINUE, 'ROLE_ADMIN')
        ;
    }

    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        $name = TextField::new('name');
        $cellphone = TelephoneField::new('cellphone');
        $email = EmailField::new('email')
            ->formatValue(
                function ($value) {
                    return is_null($value) ? '' : $value;
                }
            )
        ;
        $createdAt = DateTimeField::new('createdAt');
        $pincheck = AssociationField::new('pincheck')
            ->formatValue(
                function ($value) {
                    return is_null($value) ? '' : $value;
                }
            )
        ;
        $stamps = AssociationField::new('stamps');
        $id = IntegerField::new('id', 'ID');

        if (Crud::PAGE_INDEX === $pageName) {
            return [$name, $cellphone, $email, $createdAt];
        }
        if (Crud::PAGE_DETAIL === $pageName) {
            return [$id, $name, $cellphone, $email, $createdAt, $pincheck, $stamps];
        }
        if (Crud::PAGE_NEW === $pageName || Crud::PAGE_EDIT === $pageName) {
            $name->setLabel('Nombre y apellido');
            $cellphone->setLabel('Teléfono (solo números)');
            $email->setLabel('Email (opcional)');
        }
        if (Crud::PAGE_NEW === $pageName) {
            return [$name, $cellphone, $email];
        }
        if (Crud::PAGE_EDIT === $pageName) {
            return [$name, $cellphone, $email];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution in the EasyAdmin git issues: [[EA3] add validation groups #3690](https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/issues/3690)

I had to add the *setFormOptions* method to the crud configuration

```
// LeadCrudController
public function configureCrud(Crud $crud): Crud
{
    return $crud
        ...
        ->setFormOptions(['validation_groups' => ['Default', 'creation']], ['validation_groups' => ['Default', 'creation']])
    ;
}
```

Comment: You don't have to specify the second parameter (anymore?) if it is identical to the first one.